# Hide keyboard when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, button, keyboard, hide

I'm trying to hide my keyboard when a button is pressed. I'm using GCD to simultaneously fetch `NSData` from a server and show an animation.

The problem is, whenever I press the button the keyboard stays active. I've tried putting the  `_self.view.endEditing(true)` into the GCD function but with no success.

I would greatly appreciate if you would help me with this.

```
 @IBAction func tragi(sender: UIButton) {



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in
        if let _self = self {

             SwiftSpinner.show("Fetching data.....")


            _self.parseJSON2 { (makeModel) in
                print("print this")
            }
        }}

}
```

Comment: Put this on your button click action: `yourtextField.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: Not working, it goes synchronous.

Comment: You have to add this line on button click.

Comment: Yes, I've added it in between @IBAction line and dispatch_async line,

Comment: update your question with new code

Answer (score 1):

Please try `self.view.endEditing(true)`

The above function causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.

This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force parameter is set to true, the text field is never even asked; it is forced to resign.

[as per Apple Docs.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1619630-endediting)

Answer (score 0):

Try make call resignFirstResponder for active object in your button action and in main queue : `someTextField.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, as above answer, it's not working, it goes synchronous again.